# what is this, and what vimscript functions are associated with it?

Tags: vim

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24856/Screenshots/p.png]

i am messing with the phpcs plugin. i made it so that the plugin call on bufwrite BUT modified the phpcs to only show the quickfix window if any violations actually occurred.

what i am having issues with is that when the quickfix window opens the buffer doesn't display the gray bar with the red '>' error symbols unless i move my cursor into the quickfix window first, then back into the buffer.

i am looking for functions i could call in my phpcs plugin such that after i open the quickfix window i can refresh that gray bar to immediately display and show the violations.

Answer (score 6):

This is the sign column.  Signs are often used by plugins to show the location of compilation errors or other problems.

Everything you could want to know about using signs can be found at `:help signs`.